# How to add record type to accounts coming in from an API connection using Triggers

Tags: apex, api

I am trying to add a record type ID to Accounts that are coming in from an API connection. Below is the trigger I am using but the trigger doesn't seem to be firing/doing anything.

```
trigger APIAccountRecordType on Account (before insert) {

for(Account a:trigger.new ){
    if(a.RecordTypeId == null){
        
        ID ARID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Individual').getRecordTypeId();
        a.RecordTypeId = ARID;
        
    }
    
}
```

I Have confirmed that when creating an account with Apex the trigger fires. Has anyone heard of API records not kicking off triggers?

Comment: Can you confirm if it is active?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yup its active!

Comment: for the integration User, it would always pickup the default recordtype in Profile/PermissionSet config. So, recordType may not be null in this case.

Comment: if you want to always assign a default recordType, remove the null check. I would also suggest to store that recordType ID in metadata or cache for better performance of the API

Comment: @SanTosh The API I am using is failing on insert saying a record type has not been selected, If it were to always pickup the default wouldn't that not be the case?

Comment: did you try removing if condition?

Comment: @SanTosh Yes, same problem happened. I Think the software we are using to retrieve the data is somehow flagging the record before the trigger has a chance to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the error message the API software was giving. Problem solved